# Unable to delete/modify tile on Fiori Launchpad Designer Page

Tags: tile, sap-fiori

I had created custom tiles in the Fiori Launchpad Designer page in 1 client and transported them to another client using scc1.
These tiles do appear in the 2nd client but I am not able to delete/modify them.
Following error shows up when I try either of those operations:

> Error (404, Not Found) in OData response for PUT
>   "/sap/opu/odata/UI2/PAGE_BUILDER_CUST/PageChipInstances(pageId='X-SAP-UI2-CATALOGPAGE%3AZCustom_TCode',instanceId='00O2TPANN50VYB2RQDSBR7AQL')":
>   HTTP request failed Details: Resource not found for segment
>   'PageChipInstance'.

When I went to the URL "server":"port"/sap/opu/odata/UI2/PAGE_BUILDER_CUST/PageChipInstances to get the list of all instances, the chip instance was not found in the list for this particular tile.
Can anyone help me on this issue on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add services using IMG path.

SAP NetWeaver > Gateway > OData Channel > Administration > General Settings  > Activate and Maintain Services

activate the following OData services:

```
/UI2/PAGE_BUILDER_CONF -This is used by the launchpad designer.
/UI2/PAGE_BUILDER_CUST - This is used by the launchpad designer.
/UI2/PAGE_BUILDER_PERS - This is used by the launchpad.
/UI2/TRANSPORT- This is used by the launchpad designer.
/UI2/INTEROP - This is used by the launchpad and launchpad designer.
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check this OSS NOte:2362083 - UI2 & USHELL upgrade to version 1.32.21 for UI Add-On 2.0 (SC: UI_700, SAP_UI 750)

### Note contents:

Symptom :

This hotfix for the UI-AddOn V2.0 contain the following fix for Software Components UI_700, SAP_UI 750:

- fix problem with reference CHIPs (causing "Resource not found for segment 'PageChipInstance'" error in SAP Fiori Launchpad Designer)

Other Terms :
1.32.21, UI Add-On v2.0, UI_700, SAP_UI 750

Reason and Prerequisites :
You have installed UI Add-On V2.0 SP01

You have upgraded the SAPUI5 version to 1.32.18 (Note 2355626 - SAPUI5 upgrade to version 1.32.18).

Solution :
Please apply the attached correction

Regards,

Bharanidharan S P M